# Find content of C register after execution in microprocessor

Tags: microprocessors

Find content of 'C' register after execution of following assembly program

```
      MVI A, 17H
LOOP: RLC
      JNC LOOP
      MOV C,A
      HLT
```

Here my doubt is when at the end we did mov c,a then output should be the value of A that is in c rather than the previous result which we got after rlc instruction. But this didn't happen ..why so?

Comment: Maybe RLC stands for Rotate Left with Carry, done on A. Then the result would be a prime number. 8085 processor? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/instruction-type-rlc-in-8085-microprocessor

Comment: No it is without carry..but shouldn't the ans be the data shifted from A to C at at the end??

Comment: JNC looks like Jump on No-Carry, so I doubt it. Also old processors had the Accumulator register A being for computations like rotate and add.

Comment: By the way, if I am right, replacing 17H with 0 would cause an endless loop. Knowing the evilness of such training, that will probably be asked.